# How can I import a redux saga yield into my detox + jest test file. I need gain access to data stored in the redux store in my test setup

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, jestjs, redux-saga

This is a react-native application and I am currently writing some end-to-end testing.

A token is stored in the redux store shown below and I am testing the login functionality using detox/jest. I need to detect if the token exists in the store in my login.spec.js . If the token exists I want to wipe it from the store so the user is not logged in automatically when i reload the app to take the user back to another scene. The main function in question is the refreshUserToken() and line:-

```
const { refresh_token } = yield select(token);
```

Here is the redux saga file User.js located at:-MyApp/App/Sagas/User.js

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, select } from "redux-saga/effects";
import Config from "MyApp/App/Config";
import API from "MyApp/App/Services/API";
import { when } from "MyApp/App/Helpers/Predicate";
import Credentials from "MyApp/App/Helpers/Credentials";
import ActionCreator from "MyApp/App/Actions";

const appendPayload = payload => {
  return {
    ...payload,
    // Removed because no longer needed unless for testing purposes.
    // username: Config.TEST_USERNAME,
    // password: Config.TEST_PASSWORD,
    client_id: Config.CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: Config.CLIENT_SECRET,
  };
};

const token = state => state.token;

const user = state => state.user;


const attemptUserLogin = function*(action) {
  const { payload } = action;
  const login = "/oauth/token";
  const grant_type = "password";
  const loginPayload = appendPayload(payload);

  action.payload = {
    ...loginPayload,
    grant_type,
  };

  yield attemptUserAuthorisation(login, action);
};

const attemptUserRegister = function*(action) {
  const register = "/api/signup";
  const { payload } = action;
  yield Credentials.save(payload);
  yield put(ActionCreator.saveUserCredentials(payload));
  yield attemptUserAuthorisation(register, action);
};

const refreshUserToken = function*(action) {
  const login = "/oauth/token";
  const grant_type = "refresh_token";
  const { refresh_token } = yield select(token);

  action.payload = {
    ...action.payload,
    grant_type,
    refresh_token,
  };
  yield attemptUserAuthorisation(login, action);
};

const watchExampleSaga = function*() {
  yield takeEvery(ActionCreator.AUTO_USER_LOGIN, autoUserLogin);
  yield takeEvery(ActionCreator.USER_LOGIN, attemptUserLogin);
  yield takeEvery(ActionCreator.USER_REGISTER, attemptUserRegister);
  yield takeEvery(ActionCreator.USER_REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshUserToken);
};

export default watchExampleSaga;
```

Here is my detox/jest spec file located at:-MyApp/App/e2e/login.spec.js

```
    describe('Login Actions', () => {

  it('Should be able to enter an email address', async () => {
    await element(by.id('landing-login-btn')).tap()
    const email = 'banker@dovu.io'

    await element(by.id('login-email')).tap()
    await element(by.id('login-email')).replaceText(email)
  });

  it('Should be able to enter a password', async () => {
    const password = 'secret'

    await element(by.id('login-password')).tap()
    await element(by.id('login-password')).replaceText(password)
  });

  it('Should be able to click the continue button and login', async () => {
    await element(by.id('login-continue-btn')).tap()
    await waitFor(element(by.id('dashboard-logo'))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(500)

    // If token exists destroy it and relaunch app. This is where I need to grab the token from the redux saga!
    await device.launchApp({newInstance: true});
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handled a similar scenario:

in package.json scripts:
    "start:detox": "RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.tsx,e2e.ts node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",

In my detox config:
        "build": "ENVFILE=.env.dev;RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.tsx,e2e,ts npx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 7'",

That lets me write MyFile.e2e.tsx which replaces MyFile.tsx whilst detox is running

In the test version of that component I have buttons which are tapped in the tests and the buttons dispatch redux actions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this actually cant be done unless someone can give me a solution other than mocking the state which still wouldn't work in this case my app checks for real states to auto login.

I did get to the stage of creating a new action getUserToken and exporting that into my jest file. However the action returns undefined because the jest file requires a dispatch method like in containers.js. If anyone could provide me with a method of this using jest I would be very happy.